# how to change reviews title text in single product page oceanwp

Tags: php, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctbiq.png)

I WANT TO CHANGE REVIEW TITLE AS SHOWN IN SCREENSHOT
THANKS IN ADVANCE ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you try this hook ?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs','change_tabs');
function change_tabs($tabs){
  $tabs['reviews']['title'] = 'My new title';
  return $tabs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This generates a new tab but doesn't replace the name of the tab "valoraciones" (reviews in english) to the new title I want to give them

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).